# speeding up Euclidean distance calculation for knn

Tags: matlab, performance

I am writing a KNN code and when I use pdist or pdist2 it is so slow. When I use the traditional formula for calculating the Euclidean distance it is way faster. Why is that? Is there a way to make it even faster?

```
%temp = [F1(i, j), F2(i, j); Xtrain(sample, 1), Xtrain(sample, 2)];
meshgrid_point = [F1(i, j), F2(i, j)];
sample_point = [Xtrain(sample, 1), Xtrain(sample, 2)];
%euclidean_distance = pdist(temp, 'euclidean');
%%euclidean_distance = pdist2(meshgrid_point, sample_point, 'euclidean');
euclidean_distance = sqrt((meshgrid_point(1) - sample_point(1))^2 + (meshgrid_point(2) - sample_point(2))^2);
```

Comment: In your example code you compute the distance between two points. `pdist2` computes the distance between all pairs of points of the two inputs. Thus if you input a matrix with N points and one with M points, you get N*M distances. I don't think it is any faster computing that with hand-written MATLAB code. But `pdist2` might have a lot of overhead if you only give it one pair of points.

Answer (score 3):

You can easily get like x8 gain in speed if you copy the 'pdist' and 'pdist2' equivalent mexes ("pdist2mex.mexw64" and "pdistmex.mexw64") from matlab directory(use search to find them) to your project directory and use them. (be aware that the vector input convention is transposed version of the pdist.m and pdist2.m)